# BluetoothChat problems send message

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to create application ,which can connect Droid and another device with bluetooth
I use BluetoothChat as for example to connect Motorola Droid and Nokia N97

They were paired and connect. But when I send message ,connection lost immediatly

How can I solve this problem?

---

This is my code:

```
private void sendMessage(String message) {
   // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }


    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
```

This is ConnectThread

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice

        int RFCOMM_CHANEL = 1; //SPP chanel 
        Method m;

            try {
                m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new 
                 Class[] { int.class });
                mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, 
                         RFCOMM_CHANEL); 


            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");


        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BluetoothChatService.this.start();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

```
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();

            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;

        Log.i("BluetoothChatService","InputStream"+mmInStream);
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);


                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * @param buffer  The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What errors do you see in the log (`adb logcat`) when it disconnects?

Comment: This is error
06-25 10:57:25.858: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(6170): disconnected
06-25 10:57:25.858: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(6170): java.io.IOException: Software caused connection abort
06-25 10:57:25.858: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(6170):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readNative(Native Method)
06-25 10:57:25.858: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(6170):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:286)
06-25 10:57:25.858: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(6170):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)

Comment: 06-25 10:57:25.858: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(6170):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:341)
06-25 10:57:25.858: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(6170):     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:138)
06-25 10:57:25.858: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(6170):     at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChatService$ConnectedThread.run(BluetoothChatService.java:435)

Comment: In the line 435(BluetoothChatService.java) I read bytes:

bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);